# Global Javascript Style extension for firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Suppose I open a new tab in chrome or firefox, I want to set default js behaviour like than the tab will behave like

`<script>if($('.btn-primary').click()){ $('.btn-warning').click(); }</script>`

that code for any website. without set specific website.

I tried some extension are I have to select specific website but I don't want to select specifically. I want it will work for globally so what I have to do now?

Answer (score 0):

you need to request tabs in the permissions folder and you can put  like and it should work on all urls.

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"<all_urls>"
]
```

That should let you work you script into any webpage.